# How to swap 1st byte of num1 with last byte of num2 in C?

Tags: c

I am swapping 1st byte of a `num1` with last byte of `num2`, I tried but got particular byte of a 32 bit int through `((num1>>8*n)&0xff)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this

```
long num1 = 0x000000ff;
long num2 = 0xcc000000;

long temp = num1;
num1 = (((unsigned long)num1) & 0xffffff00) | ((((unsigned long)num2) >> 24) & 0x000000ff);
num2 = (((unsigned long)num2) & 0x00ffffff) | ((((unsigned long)temp) << 24) & 0xff000000);     

printf ("num1 : %#010lX\n", num1);
printf ("num2 : %#010lX\n", num2);
```

With mask usage we shall cover wanted part of the 32 bit value and eliminate negative influence of signed values, than concat parts of value by bitwise OR.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Code has troubles when 1) shifting in the sign bit 2) `int` is not 32-bit 3) wrong `printf()` specifier for an `int`.

Comment: @chux: as i posted above mask will deal with sign shifting, i agree than int is not always 32 bit and %p specifiers display the pointer adsress in hex so i simply decide to use it to display the values in 32 bit hex.

Comment: An example of it working does not mean the answer is without implementation nor undefined behavior.  "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right."  C11 spec.  Using the wrong specifier --> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined." C11 §7.21.6.1 9.  On my machine the result is `num1 : 0xcc num2 : 0xff000000`  Other may yield far different results.

Comment: Using unsigned variable will help with the first point.  Using match printf specifiers will help with the last.

Comment: @chux: Shifting 0x8000000 (signed) to 24 bits right gives as 0xffffff80. When we apply the mask 0x000000ff it gives to us correct result 0x00000080.

Comment: @chux:  Thats I whant to tell you about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98993/discussion-between-chux-and-mykola).

Answer (score 1):

To swap first byte of `num1` with last byte of `num2`, use this code:

```
unsigned long low = (num1 & 0x000000ff) << 24;
unsigned long high = num2 >> 24;
num1 = (num1 & 0xffffff00) | high;
num2 = (num2 & 0x00ffffff) | low;
```

Assuming `x` the input number as `unsigned long`. Use this code to swap first and last bytes of same number:

```
unsigned long high = (x >> 24);
unsigned long low = (x & 0x000000ff) << 24;
unsigned long temp = (x & 0x00ffff00);
unsigned long output = (temp | high | low);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find union quite easy to cope with this kind of byte operations:

```
typedef union myUnion
{
    int i;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
};

...
void swap(unsigned char *l, unsigned char *r)
{
    unsigned char temp = *l;
    *l = *r;
    *r = *l;
}

...

union myUnion u_a, u_b;
u_a.i = ...;
u_b.i = ...;
swap(&u_a.bytes[0], &u_b.bytes[3]);
```